# Why is (1 < NaN) false in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Why does `(1 < NaN)` give back `false` and not `undefined` (in JavaScript)?

In "11.8.5 The Abstract Relational Comparison Algorithm" it says that if either of the values is NaN (after ToPrimitive and ToNumber which should not affect NaN in my view) the result is `undefined`.

In FF and Chrome I get:

```
console.log(1 < NaN);
// false
```

Why is that?

Comment: +1 for quoting the spec in a question. :-)

Comment: You should definitely look into false/NaN/0/undefined/""/null problems of Javascript. It's horribly inconsistent and one of most serious flaws of this (otherwise quite nice) language.

Comment: @SF: And if it had been really strict, people would complain about *that* instead. :-) The rules aren't really all that bad, and in fact this particular example has nothing to do with the false/NaN/0/undefined/""/null thing. It's more that the specification has this section saying how relations work, but you then have to look elsewhere to see that having done the work in the quoted section, there's more that the actual operator does.

Answer (score 15):

Because the `<` operator returns `false` when the abstract relational algorithm returns `undefined`. See [Section 11.8.1](http://es5.github.com/#x11.8.1):

> **11.8.1 The Less-than Operator ( `<` )**
>
> The production RelationalExpression : *RelationalExpression < ShiftExpression* is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let *lref* be the result of evaluating *RelationalExpression*.
> 2. Let *lval* be GetValue(*lref*).
> 3. Let *rref* be the result of evaluating *ShiftExpression*.
> 4. Let *rval* be GetValue(*rref*).
> 5. Let *r* be the result of performing abstract relational comparison *lval < rval*. (see [11.8.5](http://es5.github.com/#x11.8.5))
> 6. If *r* is **undefined**, return **false**. Otherwise, return *r*.

This is true of all of the relational operators. The *algorithm* has an `undefined` outcome, but the *operators* convert that to `false`. And that makes sense. `1` *isn't* `< NaN` (nor is it `> NaN`, or `== NaN`, or... :-) ).

(Nice to see people reading the spec.)